# How to disable the internal or builtin speaker using alsa?

Tags: sound, alsa, hardware, speakers, microsoft-teams

How is the internal speaker below:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 23:06:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

disabled entirely so that it's removed even from the settings in `GNOME` for sound?  Using `alsa` [only](https://askubuntu.com/q/1358258/847449).

Something like:

```
sudo alsa force-unload
```

but for a [specific](https://askubuntu.com/a/162393/847449) device only.

Hardware details:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo lshw -class sound
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:e1a60000-e1a63fff
  *-usb:0
       description: Audio device
       product: USB Audio Device
       vendor: C-Media Electronics Inc.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:1.3
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Comment: You just asked the same question 20 mins ago.

Comment: this is about alsa, the other question was not related to alsa.

Comment: both ask how to disable sound device and should have been one question.

Comment: well, it seems that `pactl` is the tool to use, perhaps.  But I don't know.  Perhaps there are three ways to disable the internal speaker:  through kernel modules, alsa, and even through `pulseaudio`.  That seems quit seperate to me.